Assign user roles depending on webform submission
I have a Drupal site that is giving memberships to a collaborative body spread across several Universities.  I am new to Drupal 10, and I have the Rules alpha, and Webform Rules installed.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
When a guest comes to our website, and fills out the Webform, they will be asked to choose a Role.  These roles have already been created.  How can I make the submission of the Webform trigger a Rule that assigns one of these Roles to the person submitting?  Would they have to have an account already on the site?  I was hoping Anonymous people could be granted User Roles in this fashion, but this is kind of at the limits of my Drupal knowledge.  I am not a programmer, and our sites cannot have too much custom coding anyway... Anyone point me in the right direction?

There must be an account to have a role.

What is your purpose of granting the roles?  In Drupal, roles are used to manage access to the site resources, so it seems a little dangerous to let people choose their own access permissions.

its not a "Role" in the drupal sense, its more of a category.  they would be entitled to different levels of content based on which level they paid for... At least, thats how i understand it

That is the definition of "role" in the Drupal sense - a Drupal role gives you a set of permisisons, so different Drupal roles can access different content if you wish. That's the whole purpose of Drupal roles - to control what a user is allowed to do on your site. The Rules module can be used to assign a specific role when a webform is submitted. But anonymous users cannot have roles in Drupal, because to the Drupal website all anonymous users are treated the same way.
